# Is it possible to check empty label during training using HDF5 layer?

Tags: deep-learning, caffe

I am using HDF5 data layer. The layer will read the image and its label (from the list.txt) and feed them to the network.

```
layer {
  name: "data"
  type: "HDF5Data"
  top: "data"
  top: "label"
  include {
    phase: TRAIN
  }
  hdf5_data_param {
    source: "./list.txt"
    batch_size: 10
    shuffle: true
  }
}
```

Because my list.txt contain some image with the empty label (means black image). I want to check if the empty label is selected during the training. In CAFFE, can we do it?

Comment: Are you sure you are using HDF5Layer correctly??

Comment: What does it means correctly? In my dataset, I have some images that their label is empty(blank image). I just want to detect when the blank image is selected. For example, I have training image from `image0,...image10`, and its label is `label0, ...label10`. I know that `label5` is a blank image. I want to know when the label5 is selected.

Comment: so, when you make your hdf5 files, you can skip this label and not write that image to the hdf5 data file

Comment: No no. I must write it although it has no meaning. It is one part of training set

Comment: what does it do in the training set if it has no meaning?

Comment: Actually, you can think it is a cropping method. Given an image, you can crop it into many patches. In which, some patch is no meaning due to the blank label. However, we do not know the patch has a blank label because it is random. So, we must save all into dataset

Comment: what loss layer are you using?

Comment: I am using softmaxwithloss

Comment: then you can use ignore_label parameter in the loss layer you are using

Comment: I cannot ignore it also. Because the label also appears in the object region. For example, you have a circle and a hole in the middle of the circle. The hole has a label is zero (blank) and outside of circle also the blank. If you ignore the class zero, so you cannot classify the hole